# Nsurlrequest [get/post] to gcdwebserver urlQuery null

Tags: ios, gcdwebserver

I am working on gcdwebserver,i am sending post request to gcdwebserver,sending some params also,but in addhandlermatchblock not getting query params,please reply

code:

```
    NSString * postString=@"name=ram&age=20";
   NSURLSession * session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html"];
    NSMutableURLRequest * request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 


[webServer addHandlerWithMatchBlock:^GCDWebServerRequest *(NSString* requestMethod, NSURL* requestURL, NSDictionary* requestHeaders, NSString* urlPath, NSDictionary* urlQuery) {

        if (![requestMethod isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
            return nil;
        }


        return [[GCDWebServerRequest alloc] initWithMethod:requestMethod url:requestURL headers:requestHeaders path:urlPath query:urlQuery];

    } processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse *(GCDWebServerRequest* request) {
            NSLog(@"coming here get %@",request.urlQuery); // null
        GCDWebServerResponse* response = nil;

        return response;

                              }];
```

Comment: See examples in REASME: https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer#advanced-example-2-implementing-forms

Comment: i have seen that code,but in addHandlerWithMatchBlock my request class is GCDWebServerRequest, i tried  with this code but i didn't get value      NSString* value = [[(GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest*)request arguments] objectForKey:@"name"];

Comment: inside addHandlerWithMatchBlock for request method post how to get params

Comment: how to add requestclass in addHandlerwithmatchblock for get and post methods,if i use GCDWebServerURLEncodeFormRequest for post i am getting params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest in place of GCDWebServerRequest ,it worked

```
  [webServer addHandlerWithMatchBlock:^GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest *(NSString* requestMethod, NSURL* requestURL, NSDictionary* requestHeaders, NSString* urlPath, NSDictionary* urlQuery) {

            if (![requestMethod isEqualToString:@"GET"])
            {
                return [[GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest alloc] initWithMethod:requestMethod url:requestURL headers:requestHeaders path:urlPath query:urlQuery];
            }
            else
            {
                return [[GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest alloc] initWithMethod:requestMethod url:requestURL headers:requestHeaders path:urlPath query:urlQuery];
            }

        } processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse *(GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest * request) {

 NSMutableDictionary * dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[request arguments]]; // url query params


    return response;
    }
```